# how do i display all item from my local storage when key is unknown

Tags: html, json, object, local-storage

html form where email is taken as key.
rest all input is stored in local storage key values

i want to display on the firstname and last name in a table

```
{
        let user={
            FirstName: document.getElementById("formReg").Firstname.value,
            LastName: document.getElementById("formReg").Surname.value,
            pass1: document.getElementById("formReg").pswd.value,
            email: document.getElementById("formReg").email.value,
            dateofbirth: document.getElementById("formReg").birthday.value,
            score:0,
        };

        alert(JSON.stringify(user));
        localStorage.setItem(user.email,JSON.stringify(user));
```

Comment: `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(user.emal))["FirstName"]`

Comment: i need to access it on a different page

Comment: That will not change the call except perhaps `user.emal` is not available there. But the call is the same - of course ONLY if the page is from the same origin as the other page